# Get messageID when I the bot publish an activity

Tags: api, frameworks, bots, microsoft-teams

Can we have the messageID created when my bot posts a new activity ?
Actually, I can just get the ActivityID, but I can't link this activity to his thread. I need this identification to find the parent of one of the answers.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Your bot is posting proactively, i.e. not in response to something a user typed?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Yes, I'm posting proactively, my bot creates a new thread, and I want to reply in my thread without any mentions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js Microsofts "botbuilder" framework, "session.message.address.conversation.id" will hold the conversation's thread ID.

Where/how are you planning to use this id?

Comment: I'm using the REST api